# Separate Rails Admin Interface for Super Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, admin, rails-admin

**Goal:**
I want to create a separate Rails Admin Interface for a `Super Admin` to manage `Admins`.

**Current Situation:**
I currently have my normal Rails Admin setup where an Admin logs in to create stuff.

**Situation I'm going for:** 
I want a single user that is called `Super Admin` who can manage the `Admin`s that can create stuff. This `Super Admin` would have the option to:

- Create
- Remove
- Edit

any Admin users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question and my own Situation.

What did I do:
-> Added column "user_admin" to my User Model 
-> Since I'm using cancan I can manage my admin users from Ability, more information is found here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Cancan

When a user is an admin_user he can manage everything but when I login with my SuperAdmin I can manage all + User model

Answer (score 1):

Just have another controller and views then check whether the current admin is a super admin and if not redirect them away.

Comment: Please provide a code example how can I check if the current_user is Super Admin or not in rails_admin.rb. I tried it with current_user but no user is set in rails_admin.rb.

Comment: [Rails Admin Blog Post](http://amrithaprasad.com/2012/09/19/getting-started-with-rails_admin.html)

Something like this would work, just define super admin emails seperately

Comment: I'm currently using cancan, so I probably have to change it. Or can I do this using cancan?

Comment: Yes you can do it with cancan as you've found

    `if user.role == "super"
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role == "admin"
      can :manage, :all
      cannot :manage, User
    end`